# Spring Boot and Eureka: eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled property not found

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I have a Spring Boot Hystrix dashboard application where in a `.property` file I am trying to define some key/value pair(s) ― as per tutorial: https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/spring-cloud-hystrix-example/

I am getting error when adding property `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled = true`. The editor complains with:

> Unknown property 'eureka.client.healthcheck'

Please, help me to find out the correct dependency, or if I am missing anything else.